# My SSE2 Flooring function has some problems

Tags: c++, optimization, sse

So I wrote a function using SSE2 that floors a vector but it seems to only work for certain purposes for example it works fine for my bi-linear filtering algorithm but when used to perform a modulo it comes up with values that are slightly off. The function works by performing a conversion to an integer vector using truncation and converts that back to floating point. Both the floor and modulo code is listed below:

```
inline __m128 floor_SIMD(const __m128 & a)
{
    __m128i int_val = _mm_cvttps_epi32(a);
    return _mm_cvtepi32_ps(int_val); 
}

inline __m128 mod_SIMD(const __m128 & x, const __m128 & y)
{
    return _mm_sub_ps(x, _mm_mul_ps(y, floor_SIMD(_mm_div_ps(x, y))));
}
```

Might anyone have an explanation as to why I'm getting slightly odd values from my modulo?

EDIT: For example when one uses mod_SIMD(_mm_set1_ps(63.6f), _mm_set1_ps(32.0f)) it will produce a faulty answer but mod_SIMD(_mm_set1_ps(23.6f), _mm_set1_ps(32.0f)) will produce a correct answer. When I replace the floor function with a much less efficient component wise version it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide sample code the reproduces the problem?

Comment: Yeah the mod function is the the code with the problem. it works fine for every value that is less then y but fails if it exceeds y. I'll post a sample usage.

Comment: `it will produce a faulty answer` - what is that answer?

Comment: I just realized what the problem is. The floor function doesn't work for negative numbers because of the way I truncate it the floor of -3.3 will be -3 when it really should be -4

Comment: Why not just use `_mm_floor_ps` ? Do you need to support old CPUs without SSE4 or something ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own problem. For the benefit of everybody here is my resulting code. it subtracts one from the value if its greater than the original value which compensates for the truncation problem

```
inline __m128 floor_SIMD(const __m128 & a)
{
    static const __m128 one = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f);

    __m128 fval = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvttps_epi32(a));

    return _mm_sub_ps(fval, _mm_and_ps(_mm_cmplt_ps(a, fval), one));
}
```

Comment: This version still has problems; it will give you floor(-1) = -2, which you don’t want.  Instead conditionally subtract 1 if `a < fval`.

Comment: @StephenCanon Oops I guess I didn't test thoroughly enough I edited my code at your suggestion and it works properly now. The answer has been edited as well.